# Foursquare API - Sign up if user does not have account

Tags: android, api, foursquare

My application is using the Foursquare API with some calls that requires the access token. My question is that when I am retrieving the access token and redirect the user to Foursquare to Log In, I see that their is a Sign up link. When I click the link the user get directed to the playstore. I do not want the user to download the Foursquare App. I want them to be able to signup with a web view.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user does not have a Foursquare account and needs to sign up for one, it's very likely that they do not have the app itself either. The best way to experience and learn about Foursquare is through the native app itself—it is difficult to teach a user why they should use Foursquare through a mobile web experience. There is a sign-up flow that users can go through with the native app.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using [socialauth android](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/)

The api provides foursquare login to get profile and contacts. using access token you can make your own custom calls.